# replace substrings in string using regex groups

Tags: java, regex

I can't find the correct way to remove substrings case insensitive equals to "null" and replacing them with an empty string against a huge input data string, which contains many lines and uses **;** as a separator.

To simplify here is an example of what I am looking for:

**Input string**

```
Steve;nuLL;2;null\n
null;nullo;nUll;Marc\n
....
```

**Expected Output**

```
Steve;;2;\n
;nullo;;Marc\n
...
```

**Code**

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)(^|;)(null)(;|$)").matcher(dataStr);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1) + "" + matcher.group(3));
}
return sb.toString();
```

Can this be solved by using regex?

**EDIT:**

From the java code above I only get the first match ever being replaced, but not every appearance in the line and in the data stream. For whatever reason the `matcher.find()` is only executed once.

Comment: Can you specify what output are you getting from `sb.toString()`?  Is it an error? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: @mjuarez I edited my question, pls take a look

Comment: Is it one big string with embedded newline chars, or a List of strings?

Comment: @Bohemian its a big string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return dataStr.replaceAll("(?smi)\\bnull\\b", "");
```

- `\b` is the word boundary.
- `(?i)` is a command with i=ignore case.
- (`(?s)` is DOT_ALL, `.` matching newline characters too.)
- `(?m)` is MULTI_LINE.

---

You forgot `appendTail`, for all after the last replacement.
If the string contains more than one line, add the MULTI_LINE option for reinterpretation of `^` and `$`. See the javadoc of `Pattern`.

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1) + "" + matcher.group(3));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
```

Alternatively with lambda:

```
String result = matcher.replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1) + mr.group(3));
```

where `mr` is a freely named `MatchResult` provided by `replaceAll`.

Comment: Hi, what is ?s and ?m doing? Pls take a look at my edit in the question

Comment: @Niki `?s` is irrelevant here. Multiline not. Extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably what to replace `null` as long as it is followed by some characters, like:

```
first.replaceAll("(?i)(null)(?=[;$\\\n])", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)\\bnull\\b", "");
```

`(?1)` means "ignore case". `\b` means "word boundary". Embedded newlines are irrelevant.